# Why use react native when it is shown to be slow

Tags: react-native, nativescript

I am referring to this particular piece of comparison, which shows react-native much smaller compared to nativescript. 
https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-iOS-Profiling/tree/performance-tests

Am I paying too much attention to the speed or this numbers does not mean much?

Comment: Not everything is purely about speed, and React Native is significantly faster than a hybrid mobile app. It's also a great ecosystem.

Comment: @hermitian when it comes to comparison it depends on many factors like performance, supporting forum, learning curve, available libraries. I believe native script is good but there are less supporting forums available when you stuck in some problem. I have created a [decision matrix](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fwbchCwoIWK07cREyyla5vnpD57LZaYz2q_PtPu_tTU/edit?usp=sharing) for this comparison.

Comment: So those tests are about handling huge amount of data, but how about just rendering/painting? Seems to me it's not really the same things even though computations are involved in both cases

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, you're talking about one (1) metric, the startup time. If you look at the other tables, you'll see that NativeScript beats React Native on all other metrics (in this test).

That being said. These performance metrics means very little in real world implementations. I'm not saying that performance is unimportant, but there's a lot of things which goes into your choice of technology.

In this particular case where you weigh React Native against NativeScript, the most important question is; "Do I like the React (then go for React Native), do I like Angular 2 (then go for NativeScript), don't I want neither React nor Angular (then go for NativeScript).

With both React Native and NativeScript you'll be able to build apps which will be perceived as fast and snappy. Notice that the performance charts measures things up to 1 million(!) repetitions.

Personally I've built apps both with NativeScript and React Native. The performance of the frameworks is not a problem.